# How do I observe TCP connection variables for a process on Linux?

Tags: linux, performance, sockets, tcp

I have a distributed application where I can load a large batch of data into it. Unfortunately, my application isn't able push data over the network as fast as I'd expect: if I scp over the file, the network bandwidth (as reported by `dstat --net`) is ~120Mb/s, whereas my application only pushes ~80Mb/s.

How do I observe the TCP connection variables for the sockets used by my process to figure out where the bottleneck is? In particular, I would love to measure:

- the cwnd size for my sockets
- the current receive / send buffer size for my sockets
- the rate of TCP retransmissions / dup ACKs / etc on my socket

Comment: You can see the socket buffer sizes from the code. The single best thing you can do for performance is raise the size of the socket receive buffer.

Comment: @EJP -- is there a way to check the receive buffer size for a socket from an external process? Examining it from the process is not viable (if the process is blocked because the buffer is full, if you want periodic data, etc). Also, raising the socket receive buffer size won't help in a myriad of circumstances, including if the send end is slow (e.g. blocking on disk io), or if there are a lot of TCP retransmissions due to network errors or congestion, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- cwnd size I can see via `cat /proc/net/tcp` (its the second to last column).
- I can see the current count of outstanding bytes in the socket send / receive buffers by looking at `/proc/net/tcp` or `netstat --tcp`, although that doesn't also show me the max send buffer size.
- TCP retransmissions are harder, but this gets pretty close: https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/net/tcpretrans